# Plot two data frames against one another for correlation

Tags: r, database, statistics, correlation

Coding noob here so any help would be much appreciated!

I have sorted my data into 2 sets and would like to plot them against each other in a scatter graph. Could anyone give me some pointers on how to do this, please?

Data set 1

```
    Month   Longitude   Latitude    Pet
1   2019-01 -2.717651   52.06777    Dog
2   2019-01 -2.743951   52.07546    Dog
3   2019-01 -2.738952   52.07496    Dog
4   2019-01 -2.703526   52.06291    Dog
.   .        .          .           .
.   .        .          .           .
86  2019-01 -2.711884   52.06379    Dog
```

Data set 2

```
    Month   Longitude   Latitude    Pet
1   2019-01 -1.717651   52.77       Cat
2   2019-01 -2.543951   51.07546    Cat
3   2019-01 -0.38952    52.07496    Cat
4   2019-01 -1.703526   50.91       Cat
5   2019-01 -2.703526   52.06291    Cat
6   2019-01 -2.698765   52.06345    Cat
.   .        .          .           .
.   .        .          .           .
71  2019-01 -2.711884   52.06379    Cat
```

How do I plot these data frames against each other please? As id like to check for correlation.

Comment: Can you describe what the final output would look like? What would be on x and y axis?

Comment: So the x axis would represent the location of the Cats on a map against the y axis of the dogs on the map.

Comment: It sounds strange to plot x for cat and y for dog. wouldn't it be better  to plot x-y cat in one color and x-y dogs in another colors? What do you exactly mean by "check for correlation"

Comment: Cat and dog are just the labels I used but yes perhaps the distance between the points (Euclidian distance maybe) would be much better to do than plot the resulting data. The problem is as I am very new to the language I have no idea how to program it

Comment: Also, use `dput()` to provide us with a miminal example to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your data it seems like you are comparing between dogs and cats. The headings of the two data sets are the same so they can be combined.

```
combined_data <- rbind(dataset1, dataset2)
```

You can still uniquely identify both original datasets as they are identified as "Dog" or "Cat" in the 'Pet' heading of combined_data.

You can then plot the graph, with different colours differentiating dogs and cats.

```
ggplot(data = combined_data, mapping = aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) + geom_point(mapping = aes(color = Pet))
```

Hope this helps.